# creating a simple domain-specific language using xtext-xbase-xtend toolchain

Tags: java, xtext, eclipse-emf, xtend, xbase

This is for a class project for creating a domain-specific language (DSL). Nothing fancy to consider. For myself, I've set this project as purely an exercise to learning the steps involved.

Files  involved (with attached code files)::

1) Grammer in Xtext (entities.xtext)

```
grammar org.example.xbase.entities.Entities with org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.Xbase  

generate entities "http://www.example.org/xbase/entities/Entities"


Model:
    entities+=Entity*;


Entity:
    'entity' name=ID ('extends'
        superType=JvmParameterizedTypeReference)?
        '{'
            attributes+=Attribute*
            operations+=Operation*
        '}';

Attribute:
    'attr'(type=JvmTypeReference)? name=ID
    ('=' initexpression=XExpression)? ';';

Operation:
    'op'(type=JvmTypeReference)? name=ID
    '(' (params+=FullJvmFormalParameter (',' 
        params+=FullJvmFormalParameter)*)? ')'
    body=XBlockExpression;
```

2) JvmModelInferrer in xtend (entitiesJvmModelInferrer.xtend)

```
package org.example.xbase.entities.jvmmodel

import com.google.inject.Inject
import org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.jvmmodel.AbstractModelInferrer
import org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.jvmmodel.IJvmDeclaredTypeAcceptor
import org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.jvmmodel.JvmTypesBuilder
import org.eclipse.xtext.naming.IQualifiedNameProvider
import org.example.xbase.entities.entities.Entity

class EntitiesJvmModelInferrer extends AbstractModelInferrer {
@Inject extension JvmTypesBuilder
@Inject extension IQualifiedNameProvider

    def dispatch void infer(Entity entity, IJvmDeclaredTypeAcceptor acceptor, boolean isPreIndexingPhase) {
        acceptor.accept(entity.toClass("Animals."+entity.name)).
            initializeLater[
                documentation= entity.documentation
                if(entity.superType !=null)
                    superTypes += entity.superType.cloneWithProxies

                    //Create fields for each attribute in the entity
                    entity.attributes.forEach[
                        a | val type = a.type ?: a.initexpression?.inferredType
                        members += a.toField(a.name,type) [
                            documentation=a.documentation
                            if(a.initexpression !=null)
                                initializer = a.initexpression
                        ]
                        //create getter method
                        members +=a.toGetter(a.name,type)
                        //create setter method
                        members +=a.toSetter(a.name,type)
                    ]   
                    //Create method for each operation in the entity
                    entity.operations.forEach[
                        op|
                        members+= op.toMethod(op.name,op.type?:inferredType)[
                            documentation=op.documentation
                            for (p:op.params){
                                parameters +=p.toParameter(p.name,p.parameterType)
                            }
                            //create a main method in one of the classes, when called. Make sure it is also static!!!
                            if(op.name.equals('main')){
                                static=true
                            }
                            body=op.body
                        ]
                    ]

            ]
}
}
```

3) Source files in the new language (Animal.xentities and Main.xentities). The .xentities extensions are specific for files for this DSL project.
  - Main.xentities

```
entity Main{
    //define an instance of Animal
    attr me=new Animal;
    op main(){
        println('main-func')
    }
}
```

-generated Main.java

```
package Animals;

import Animals.Animal;
import org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib.Functions.Function0;
import org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib.InputOutput;

@SuppressWarnings("all")
public class Main {
  private Animal me = new Function0<Animal>() {
    public Animal apply() {
      Animal _animal = new Animal();
      return _animal;
    }
  }.apply();

  public Animal getMe() {
    return this.me;
  }

  public void setMe(final Animal me) {
    this.me = me;
  }

  public static String main() {
    //This is the main function I created to
    //have an entry point for program execution
    String _println = InputOutput.<String>println("main-func");
    return _println;
  }
}
```

-Animal.xentities

```
entity Animal{
//define an equivalent class in my domain-specific language
attr int nlegs;
op printAnimalSound(){
    println('I grunt and sniff')
}
}
```

-Generated Animal.java code

```
package Animals;

import org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib.InputOutput;

@SuppressWarnings("all")
public class Animal {
  private int nlegs;

  public int getNlegs() {
    return this.nlegs;
  }

  public void setNlegs(final int nlegs) {
    this.nlegs = nlegs;
  }

  public String printAnimalSound() {
    String _println = InputOutput.<String>println("I grunt and sniff");
    return _println;
  }
}
```

My Objective:: 
I want to develop a basic workflow infrastructure so that I can define classes with associated functions and attributes. Then I want to be able to execute them.

My problem::
Keep getting a message that says ***'selection does not contain a main type'***.

My attempt: In entity(class) 'Main.xentities', I create a 'op main()' function. In the generated .java code, this will show up as a public static String main() function. I thought this would work. However it didn't. I don't know what is missing. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Could you please post your code as text instead of images? People using screen readers or bad eye sight (the resolution is quite bad) cannot help you otherwise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, this is not going to work!! The 
main method must return void and take arguments of type String[] args; or

```
public static void main(String[] args){ ...}
```

I will need to modify the JvmModelInferrer file to make this happen.